# Grid environment for exercise solution

Tags: tcolorbox, backgrounds

Following the example in the [tcolorbox manual](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), p.  148, I produced the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
% Define box for questions
\newtcbtheorem{exemplo}{\, Exemplo}%
{ % frame stuff
    breakable,
    arc=40mm,
    size=normal,
    enhanced,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=white,colbacklower=white,
    borderline={0pt}{0pt}{blue!10},
    % margens da frame
    top=0.3cm,left=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
    lefttitle=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=0.05cm,
    coltitle=blue,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=blue!10,
}{ex}

\newfontfamily\cooljazz[NFSSFamily=cooljazz,BoldFont={Boogaloo Regular},Scale=0.85,Ligatures=TeX]{cooljazz}
\usepackage[subdued, defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\MTfamily{cooljazz}
\Mathastext[cooljazz]
% Environment for solving the questions
\newenvironment{resol}
{   \MTversion{cooljazz}\MTdonotfixfonts
    \setmainfont{cooljazz}[Scale = .8, Extension = .ttf ]
}{\par} 
% define grid backround
\newtcolorbox{notebook}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colframe=white,
    boxrule=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,
    %left=1.3in,
    underlay={%
    breakable,
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \draw[help lines,step=5mm,blue!25,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\begin{document}
    Minimum Working Example
\begin{exemplo}{Exemplo}{}
\lipsum[1-1]
\linebreak
\begin{notebook}

\begin{resol}   
    \lipsum[2-5]
\end{resol} 
\end{notebook}
\end{exemplo}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I can't align the box at the top of the page with the book class. I can with the article class, but, either way the grid box does not break across pages...
Also, the last right vertical line of the grid does not show up, neither does the last horizontal bottom line... I wonder if someone has a suggestion on how to solve this....

The problem seems to be that `tcolorbox` does not allow for a box inside another box to break....

Thanks in advance.

Addition:

I was able to get this effect:

[image]

Not perfect, but will do for now. The solution was to add

```
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \draw[help lines, step=5mm, gray25!20, shift={(interior.north west)}]
        (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}}
```

to the `exemplo`box, and then define a blank box for the heading as:

```
\newtcolorbox{note}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colframe=white,
    boxrule=-2.25mm,top=2mm,bottom=1mm,left=2mm,right=2mm}
```

It's still not perfect as the top of the grid shows up partially after the box title....

Comment: You are including `resol` box inside `exemplo` which has some non zero inner margins. I'm not sure if this is the real problem but you can consider it.

Comment: Sorry, can't see the problem... ```resol``` is not a box, just an environment. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know, what exactely you are trying to achieve here. If you just want to write some stuff on a fancy grid then you might want to check out the [WriteOnGrid](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/writeongrid) package

Comment: @JPMD my fault. I wanted to say notebook inside exemplo

Comment: @DG, See above please.

Comment: @Ignasi ok... but still not work. tcolorbox don't break inside other  tcolorbox (at least it is what the manual say). So, I added a tcb to my tcolorbox definitio and color the bacground with a white tcbox... again not breakable...

Comment: @JPMD I think I've understood the problem and have written an answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understant that OP wants a `breakable` box whith a grid background for the lower part of the box. This can be achieved with an `overlay` applied only to the lower box. Something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{exemplo}[2][]{%
    enhanced, breakable, segmentation hidden, colback=white,
    colframe=blue,
   overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \draw[help lines, step=5mm, blue!50]
        (interior.south west) grid (segmentation.south east);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{exemplo}{First}
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{exemplo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem with original codes was the use of two nested boxes. `tcolorbox` cannot break them. The code in page 148, uses two boxes, one for exercices and one for solutions, but they are not nested, the remain independent.

Comment: That is it!... a million thanks as I was not aware of the overaly function...

Comment: I see that the grid at the top does not start on a horizontal line. The last left vertical line does not also gets overlapped with the left frame line. Is it possible to align these elements. And also have the text starting at the first line of the horizontal grid? Thanks!

Comment: @JPMD I've no idea, but you can always play with the grid step or some shift on the upper reference point.

Comment: Adding ```\documentclass[11pt]{book}``` creates a white box in the second page!!??... the problem is due to the [11pt] argument....